# String to List of Arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on a ML model, and I have to convert a list of arrays (the weights of the layers) to a string, to send it over MQTT. Then I have to convert it to a list of arrays again, and thats where I don't know how to solve it. The initial look of the list is like this:

Initial list from `model.get_weights()`
:

```
[array([[ 0.05541647, -0.00467741,  0.06709623, ..., -0.06240537,
        -0.05044469, -0.06255569],
       [ 0.05793238, -0.04376897, -0.03331734, ...,  0.04109375,
        -0.05561347, -0.05630576],
       [ 0.03568218,  0.00916858,  0.02733664, ...,  0.04085189,
         0.07445424,  0.05173937],
       ...,
       [ 0.00326935,  0.05949181, -0.02493389, ...,  0.01619817,
         0.02883349, -0.00364999],
       [ 0.05162556, -0.07704586, -0.00726594, ...,  0.03567791,
         0.06234651,  0.05147751],
       [-0.04587721,  0.06365172, -0.06174358, ..., -0.07004303,
        -0.00196535, -0.05049317]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.11118214, -0.00349338,  0.18680657, ...,  0.01847704,
        -0.03098661, -0.04094526],
       [-0.06314829,  0.00289522, -0.11807185, ..., -0.10976926,
        -0.12070866,  0.19067971],
       [-0.05408052, -0.02283411,  0.16553403, ..., -0.12856016,
         0.00681128, -0.05486405],
       ...,
       [-0.12182648, -0.03314751,  0.04840027, ...,  0.13398318,
        -0.092302  ,  0.13001741],
       [ 0.01030177,  0.14168383, -0.18688273, ..., -0.17727108,
        -0.1098071 , -0.12000293],
       [ 0.03310342,  0.17201088, -0.08573408, ...,  0.15494372,
        -0.16848558,  0.12254588]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)][array([[-0.07572845,  0.07035964, -0.00726507, ..., -0.01283053,
        -0.02842413,  0.02551443],
       [-0.00741241, -0.02386538,  0.00442091, ...,  0.0693512 ,
         0.02695736, -0.07246653],
       [ 0.06941632, -0.01986459,  0.02596217, ...,  0.04713184,
         0.03926247,  0.07958693],
       ...,
       [ 0.04515444, -0.02030407, -0.00393321, ...,  0.025347  ,
        -0.01182116,  0.04929114],
       [-0.06743087,  0.02246762,  0.0225632 , ...,  0.03987813,
        -0.00048529,  0.00320805],
       [ 0.07628443, -0.06414777,  0.04115602, ..., -0.03207976,
        -0.01118261,  0.00946496]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.19875868, -0.0724885 , -0.15991165, ..., -0.04141769,
         0.11540116,  0.1246707 ],
       [ 0.03422281,  0.09608312,  0.18289839, ...,  0.20248671,
        -0.05454096, -0.11580068],
       [ 0.12459688,  0.17984338,  0.02630243, ..., -0.20585045,
        -0.08128738,  0.08814187],
       ...,
       [ 0.07335795, -0.02979451,  0.18084474, ...,  0.10529856,
        -0.01682918,  0.09111448],
       [-0.04859972,  0.00864089,  0.12390362, ...,  0.17152672,
        -0.00713953,  0.06918244],
       [ 0.07703741,  0.08441998,  0.07430147, ...,  0.08184789,
        -0.17301415, -0.11319483]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)][array([[ 0.0367789 ,  0.00915425, -0.02733853, ..., -0.02040792,
        -0.03245208,  0.05279592],
       [-0.07986325, -0.0093028 ,  0.04690679, ..., -0.03594837,
        -0.03365551,  0.04181867],
       [-0.01529652, -0.04739384, -0.04961624, ...,  0.03608193,
        -0.02728439,  0.03388698],
       ...,
       [ 0.06456115, -0.06791718,  0.02804885, ..., -0.02433868,
        -0.06182578, -0.01848171],
       [ 0.02070352, -0.03081129, -0.06013838, ...,  0.00220076,
        -0.05257946,  0.04429463],
       [-0.00666717, -0.05574629, -0.03431721, ...,  0.07651306,
         0.02397371, -0.06563253]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[-0.03700976,  0.03013754, -0.10353263, ..., -0.02945483,
         0.0997458 , -0.00535272],
       [-0.09297995, -0.00978217, -0.15470384, ...,  0.18909012,
        -0.02411154,  0.03662926],
       [-0.14865722,  0.13019712, -0.16894627, ...,  0.02009523,
         0.18213274, -0.0228352 ],
       ...,
       [-0.01553613,  0.09343223,  0.08486612, ..., -0.05365789,
         0.01778294, -0.16807753],
       [-0.18208605,  0.04372226,  0.00357029, ..., -0.19741432,
        -0.05363443,  0.02788939],
       [ 0.08774336, -0.01484367,  0.20057438, ..., -0.14653617,
        -0.01546355,  0.05677335]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)][array([[-0.06932048,  0.04931927,  0.02986243, ..., -0.00124229,
        -0.04131682,  0.04874287],
       [ 0.02503149, -0.01789933,  0.01456298, ..., -0.07483141,
        -0.00834411,  0.06528252],
       [-0.07246303, -0.05168567, -0.07982197, ...,  0.03553585,
        -0.07355539,  0.0455386 ],
       ...,
       [-0.03427464, -0.05049596,  0.04526667, ...,  0.0540349 ,
        -0.07729132,  0.02335045],
       [ 0.00899633,  0.02592985, -0.06459068, ..., -0.06000284,
        -0.06346118,  0.00611115],
       [ 0.05585308, -0.00852666, -0.01165473, ..., -0.07250661,
        -0.07178727,  0.04963235]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.1062278 ,  0.07988457, -0.20682454, ...,  0.0976506 ,
        -0.0116874 , -0.06627488],
       [ 0.02052386, -0.20188682, -0.15016697, ...,  0.15503861,
         0.04030807,  0.17274798],
       [-0.0675576 ,  0.09332336, -0.1745064 , ...,  0.07768513,
        -0.04787958,  0.06289487],
       ...,
       [-0.20753261,  0.06955643, -0.19981481, ..., -0.01403984,
         0.04701854, -0.20236667],
       [ 0.11430956,  0.02020629,  0.03855045, ..., -0.05780427,
         0.0012497 , -0.12894002],
       [ 0.1534607 , -0.18565604,  0.13524099, ..., -0.184562  ,
        -0.06643088,  0.08209728]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

but after convert it to a String it looks like this

List after convert it to String,     `weightsStr = ''.join(str(e) for e in weights)`
:

```
[[ 0.05541647 -0.00467741  0.06709623 ... -0.06240537 -0.05044469
  -0.06255569]
 [ 0.05793238 -0.04376897 -0.03331734 ...  0.04109375 -0.05561347
  -0.05630576]
 [ 0.03568218  0.00916858  0.02733664 ...  0.04085189  0.07445424
   0.05173937]
 ...
 [ 0.00326935  0.05949181 -0.02493389 ...  0.01619817  0.02883349
  -0.00364999]
 [ 0.05162556 -0.07704586 -0.00726594 ...  0.03567791  0.06234651
   0.05147751]
 [-0.04587721  0.06365172 -0.06174358 ... -0.07004303 -0.00196535
  -0.05049317]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[ 0.11118214 -0.00349338  0.18680657 ...  0.01847704 -0.03098661
  -0.04094526]
 [-0.06314829  0.00289522 -0.11807185 ... -0.10976926 -0.12070866
   0.19067971]
 [-0.05408052 -0.02283411  0.16553403 ... -0.12856016  0.00681128
  -0.05486405]
 ...
 [-0.12182648 -0.03314751  0.04840027 ...  0.13398318 -0.092302
   0.13001741]
 [ 0.01030177  0.14168383 -0.18688273 ... -0.17727108 -0.1098071
  -0.12000293]
 [ 0.03310342  0.17201088 -0.08573408 ...  0.15494372 -0.16848558
   0.12254588]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[-0.07572845  0.07035964 -0.00726507 ... -0.01283053 -0.02842413
   0.02551443]
 [-0.00741241 -0.02386538  0.00442091 ...  0.0693512   0.02695736
  -0.07246653]
 [ 0.06941632 -0.01986459  0.02596217 ...  0.04713184  0.03926247
   0.07958693]
 ...
 [ 0.04515444 -0.02030407 -0.00393321 ...  0.025347   -0.01182116
   0.04929114]
 [-0.06743087  0.02246762  0.0225632  ...  0.03987813 -0.00048529
   0.00320805]
 [ 0.07628443 -0.06414777  0.04115602 ... -0.03207976 -0.01118261
   0.00946496]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[ 0.19875868 -0.0724885  -0.15991165 ... -0.04141769  0.11540116
   0.1246707 ]
 [ 0.03422281  0.09608312  0.18289839 ...  0.20248671 -0.05454096
  -0.11580068]
 [ 0.12459688  0.17984338  0.02630243 ... -0.20585045 -0.08128738
   0.08814187]
 ...
 [ 0.07335795 -0.02979451  0.18084474 ...  0.10529856 -0.01682918
   0.09111448]
 [-0.04859972  0.00864089  0.12390362 ...  0.17152672 -0.00713953
   0.06918244]
 [ 0.07703741  0.08441998  0.07430147 ...  0.08184789 -0.17301415
  -0.11319483]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[ 0.0367789   0.00915425 -0.02733853 ... -0.02040792 -0.03245208
   0.05279592]
 [-0.07986325 -0.0093028   0.04690679 ... -0.03594837 -0.03365551
   0.04181867]
 [-0.01529652 -0.04739384 -0.04961624 ...  0.03608193 -0.02728439
   0.03388698]
 ...
 [ 0.06456115 -0.06791718  0.02804885 ... -0.02433868 -0.06182578
  -0.01848171]
 [ 0.02070352 -0.03081129 -0.06013838 ...  0.00220076 -0.05257946
   0.04429463]
 [-0.00666717 -0.05574629 -0.03431721 ...  0.07651306  0.02397371
  -0.06563253]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[-0.03700976  0.03013754 -0.10353263 ... -0.02945483  0.0997458
  -0.00535272]
 [-0.09297995 -0.00978217 -0.15470384 ...  0.18909012 -0.02411154
   0.03662926]
 [-0.14865722  0.13019712 -0.16894627 ...  0.02009523  0.18213274
  -0.0228352 ]
 ...
 [-0.01553613  0.09343223  0.08486612 ... -0.05365789  0.01778294
  -0.16807753]
 [-0.18208605  0.04372226  0.00357029 ... -0.19741432 -0.05363443
   0.02788939]
 [ 0.08774336 -0.01484367  0.20057438 ... -0.14653617 -0.01546355
   0.05677335]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[-0.06932048  0.04931927  0.02986243 ... -0.00124229 -0.04131682
   0.04874287]
 [ 0.02503149 -0.01789933  0.01456298 ... -0.07483141 -0.00834411
   0.06528252]
 [-0.07246303 -0.05168567 -0.07982197 ...  0.03553585 -0.07355539
   0.0455386 ]
 ...
 [-0.03427464 -0.05049596  0.04526667 ...  0.0540349  -0.07729132
   0.02335045]
 [ 0.00899633  0.02592985 -0.06459068 ... -0.06000284 -0.06346118
   0.00611115]
 [ 0.05585308 -0.00852666 -0.01165473 ... -0.07250661 -0.07178727
   0.04963235]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][[ 0.1062278   0.07988457 -0.20682454 ...  0.0976506  -0.0116874
  -0.06627488]
 [ 0.02052386 -0.20188682 -0.15016697 ...  0.15503861  0.04030807
   0.17274798]
 [-0.0675576   0.09332336 -0.1745064  ...  0.07768513 -0.04787958
   0.06289487]
 ...
 [-0.20753261  0.06955643 -0.19981481 ... -0.01403984  0.04701854
  -0.20236667]
 [ 0.11430956  0.02020629  0.03855045 ... -0.05780427  0.0012497
  -0.12894002]
 [ 0.1534607  -0.18565604  0.13524099 ... -0.184562   -0.06643088
   0.08209728]][0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

I'm not really sure how to return it to his original form.

Thank you!!

Comment: Also, why do you need to put it back to the original form? Can't you just use the original variable?

Comment: @Gulzar thank you for the recommendation!! I need to put it back because when I get the  weights as a string in the receptor I need to change it to the original form to setup the weights of the layers of the model in the receptor.

Comment: Please show relevant code that yields the above results

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you have numpy arrays there. In this case, I think, the best approach would be to use numpy load and save methods.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Or if you need a human readable string representation array2string and fromstring
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html

Comment: Thank you! In the case of the first methods they work for save it but I havent a string at any momento so I can't pass that variable as payload through MQTT, in the case of the second ones, the problem is that this is a list of arrays, not an array so the method doesnt work.

Comment: What i did was convert the list to a np object and then make numpy.array2string, getting a string that is equal to the list of np arrays, but i need to be a list again, and the method list() doesnt work for this, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First check with the dimension of the array that it is 2d,3d, or multi-dimension and then according to that create properly for loops to iterate through all the item of array list and use manual type casting to convert all values to string.
Example for 1D array to convert int & float to string

```
arr = [1,2,5,6,4,8,1.55,6.33,2.22,3.03,-0.222,-52222]
print(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = str(arr[i])
print(arr)
```

Output :

```
[1,2,5,6,4,8,1.55,6.33,2.22,3.03,-0.222,-52222]
['1', '2', '5', '6', '4', '8', '1.55', '6.33', '2.22', '3.03', '-0.222', '-52222']
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case what i want to convert is a list of np arrays,  not a single array